# How to get all dates between two dates in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to get all dates between `startend` and `Enddate`.I used between to get the desired result. But the between function skipping  the current date.

```
Declare @StartDate Datetime  ='2014-04-01 11:13:37'
               ,@EndDate datetime ='2014-04-04 11:13:37'
```

Query:-

```
Select * from table where date between @Startdate and @EndDate
```

Current Result:-

```
2014-04-02 11:13:37
2014-04-03 11:13:37
2014-04-04 11:13:37
```

Expected result:-

```
2014-04-01 11:13:37
2014-04-02 11:13:37
2014-04-03 11:13:37
2014-04-04 11:13:37
```

Comment: can you give some data examples of the date column in your table? Does it contain milliseconds as well?

Comment: It should not happen. *between* clause include both boundaries. Check data of **1 April** in your DB

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You Can Try this

```
Declare @StartDate Date  ='2014-04-01'
               ,@EndDate date ='2014-04-04'

                  (OR)

Declare @StartDate Datetime  ='2014-04-01  00:00:00'
               ,@EndDate datetime ='2014-04-04  12:59:59'
```

Query:-

```
Select * from table where date between @Startdate and @EndDate
```

Comment: Just so you know the first option will NOT work because your @EndDate will be converted to DATETIME with a time of 00:00:00. So any time during that date will not be returned because it will be greater than @ EndDate

Answer (score 1):

You could create a procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAllDaysBetweenTwoDate
    (
    @StartDate DATETIME,    
    @EndDate DATETIME
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @TOTALCount INT
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY,-1,@StartDate)
        Select  @TOTALCount= DATEDIFF(DD,@StartDate,@EndDate);

        WITH d AS 
                (
                  SELECT top (@TOTALCount) AllDays = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() 
                    OVER (ORDER BY object_id), REPLACE(@StartDate,'-',''))
                  FROM sys.all_objects
                )
            SELECT AllDays From d

        RETURN 
    END
    GO
```

Courtesy: [Find All the Days Between Two Dates](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/639460/Find-All-the-Days-Between-Two-Dates)

Answer (score 0):

Your query works for me perfectly.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2014-04-01 11:13:37',
        @EndDate   DATETIME = '2014-04-04 11:13:37';

WITH cte_dates
AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@startDate) dates --get dates from a month before start date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,dates)
    FROM cte_dates
    WHERE dates < DATEADD(MONTH,1,@EndDate) --up to a month after end date
)

SELECT dates
FROM cte_dates 
WHERE dates BETWEEN @Startdate AND @EndDate
```

Results:

```
dates
-----------------------
2014-04-01 11:13:37.000
2014-04-02 11:13:37.000
2014-04-03 11:13:37.000
2014-04-04 11:13:37.000
```

This means that it's probably an issue with your data, specifically the time section. If you don't need to look at time and only need specific dates, try this instead:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2014-04-01',
        @EndDate   DATE = '2014-04-04';

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CAST([date] AS DATE) BETWEEN @startDate AND @EndDate
```